# cordova inAppBrowser not working on android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I have a situation where my `inAppBrowser` is not working on android but it's working in IOS, browser and PhoneGap App.

I don't exactly know what's wrong here, but I have the feeling that the following 
errors are causing this problem

```
/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser

/com.test.wrapper I/System.out: Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser.
```

Is there anyone who is facing a similar issue? Anybody able to help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this issue is happening recently, the reason is a bug in Cordova Android 7.1.3.
Refer the following links,

[Android Class Not Found](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/355)

[Plugin doesn't install correctly](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/354)

Your best option is to stick with Cordova android 7.1.2 or upgrade to 7.1.4.

You can specify the Cordova Android version while installing like this,

```
cordova platform add android@7.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the problem. The plugin did not get added to the project.
Uninstall & reinstall the plugin.

`cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`